# SQL Server query syntax problem

Tags: sql-server

Hi can any one explain me what wrong with my query

```
SELECT    
     cDispatcherName AS Name, 
     cCallNature AS EmergencyCall, 
     COUNT(cCallNature) AS Total,
     (
        SELECT  
             COUNT(cCallNature)   
             FROM   CallInfo  
             WHERE (cCallNature ='Regular call') 
        GROUP BY cCallNature
     ) AS Expr1
FROM         CallInfo 
WHERE     (cCallNature = 'Emergency call')
GROUP BY cDispatcherName, cCallNature
```

gives this error message:

`Errormsg::There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 1,Token line offset = 93,Token in error = SELECT ]`

Comment: Do you get any error messages?

Comment: Seems valid syntax. What is the problem?

Comment: Yes.My querySELECT  cDispatcherName AS Name, cCallNature AS EmergencyCall, COUNT(cCallNature) AS Total,(SELECT COUNT(cCallNature)  FROM  CallInfo  WHERE   cCallNature = 'Regular call' GROUP BY cCallNature from Callinfo) AS Expr1  FROM CallInfo WHERE  (cCallNature = 'Emergency call') GROUP BY cDispatcherName, cCallNature     Errormsg::There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 1,Token line offset = 93,Token in error = SELECT ] I'm working on Sqlserverce Compactedtion

Comment: As the error position indicates that the problem is the "nested" SELECT inside the SELECT list, I guess SQL Server **compact edition** simply does not support this. Check the manual, it should be explained there.

Comment: Have u get any hint Ocaso......

Comment: You don't really need the GROUP BY inside the Expr1 subquery, but it's going to be the same for every row, so I am not sure if it is the intended logic anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Its not entirely clear what your after from the original query, but you can't use nested selects in SQL-CE unless they return a set (as opposed to a scalar value) so  instead try something like;

```
    SELECT    
       CallInfo.cDispatcherName AS Name, 
       cCallNature AS EmergencyCall, 
       COUNT(cCallNature) AS Total,
       SUB.CNT AS RegularCalls
    FROM CallInfo
    LEFT JOIN (
       SELECT  
          cDispatcherName,
          COUNT(*) AS CNT
       FROM  CallInfo  
       WHERE cCallNature ='Regular call'
       GROUP BY cDispatcherName
    ) AS SUB ON CallInfo.cDispatcherName = SUB.cDispatcherName

    WHERE    cCallNature = 'Emergency call'
    GROUP BY CallInfo.cDispatcherName, CallInfo.cCallNature, SUB.CNT
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this query can be written in a better way but i can see a major problem with the sub query that you didn't specified the (DispatcherName).

So change the subquery as the following

```
 (
        SELECT  
             COUNT(cCallNature)   
             FROM   CallInfo rcall  
             WHERE (cCallNature ='Regular call' and rcall.cDispatcherName =CallInfo.CallInfo ) 

     ) AS Expr1
```

Also you can change all the query (but this depends on your needs)

```
SELECT    
     cDispatcherName AS Name, 
     COUNT(cCallNature) AS EmergencyCallTotal,
     (
        SELECT  
             COUNT(cCallNature)   
             FROM   CallInfo rcall  
             WHERE (cCallNature ='Regular call' and rcall.cDispatcherName =CallInfo.CallInfo )
     ) AS RegularcallTotal
FROM         CallInfo 
WHERE     (cCallNature = 'Emergency call')
GROUP BY cDispatcherName
```